# Magento 2 wrong session_id ajax

Tags: magento-2.1, ajax, session

I have several mismatches with session_id in my production website :

- if I add a simple product to my cart with a freshly created customer, the session_id in the store switcher urls is not updated (the session_id is re-generated by magento by add to cart process) and when I switch to another store the session is lost
- when I login with an existing customer and add a configurable product to my cart, if I go to checkout process, the session_id is re-generated again in the onepage controller but the first ajax query loads with the previous session_id instead of the newly one

Some information about configuration :

- sessions are stored in files mode under /var/session/
- session file permissions are 660
- sid on frontend is enabled
- cookie domain is "*.mydomain.com"
- cookie path is empty
- cookie lifetime is 86400
- http only is off
- website is fully https

Anybody has already faced this problem ?